# Issue with AzurePowerShell@5 task: 'The term 'pwsh.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm seeing some weird behavior when trying to use the [AzurePowerShell@5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-powershell-v5?view=azure-pipelines) task in my ADO pipeline. Below is how I have the task configured:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xyz'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
    pwsh: true
    ScriptType: filePath
    ScriptPath: 'pathName'
    ScriptArguments: >
    (args)
```

Note that I set `pwsh: true` which instructs the task to use **PowerShell Core** rather than Windows PowerShell. I have verified that the latest version of PowerShell 7 is installed by running `winget install --id Microsoft.PowerShell` on the virtual machine that is used to run my pipeline. I also verified it was added to the System Path environment variable list correctly (`C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\` is in my path).

Despite all this, I am still getting the error message in the title:

> The term 'pwsh.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

To add even more confusion, the same task works in a separate pipeline that uses a different virtual machine. The System PATH environment variable on both machines have PowerShell 7 and Windows PowerShell in the list. The only noticeable difference between the two machines is that the working machine is running Windows Server 2019 Standard, while the problematic machine is running Windows 10 Enterprise. Is Windows 10 Enterprise somehow incompatible with this task?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: That should just work. Are you sure the user that's hosting the agent service has permissions to run pwsh

Comment: Have you restarted the service of the agent after installing pwsh?

Comment: @jessehouwing as in the ADO Agent service? And yes, the user is an admin on the machine.

Comment: PS uses the environmental variable PSModulePath and can be different if Admin verses user.

Comment: This is the command that is called from PowerShell 5.1 to find PowerShell Core: `Get-Command -Name pwsh.exe -CommandType Application`. Try opening a Windows PowerShell prompt and run it to see whether PowerShell Core is found.

Comment: @jessehouwing That command works when I run it locally. Unfortunately, I am still seeing the same error in the pipeline.

Comment: _EDIT:_ It is working on some machines and not working on others. Despite every machine having PowerShell 7 downloaded and `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\` added to the System Path environment variable. Not sure why the inconsistency is happening.

Comment: @LoganCodes Can you see `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7` in the `path` value in the agent capabilities page? `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_settings/agentpools?agentId={agentid}&poolId={poolid}&view=capabilities`

Comment: Hey all, thanks for your suggestions. I eventually got it working. I posted an answer below with the combination of things I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working. I'm not sure which of the suggestions below was the solution--perhaps it was a combination of some. Regardless, as suggested in the comments above, I

- Added the path for PowerShell 7 to the System PSModulePath environment variable
- Added the path for PowerShell 7 to the *User* Path environment variable.
- Restarted the ADO Agent service.